# Unable to get the road network distance between two points in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, distance, interpolation, road

```
SELECT
    sf.id,
    sf2.gid,
    SUM(ST_Distance(
            sfroads.geom,
            ST_LineInterpolatePoint(sfroads.geom_latest1, 
                ST_LineLocatePoint(sfroads.geom_latest1, sf.point_origin))
    )) +
    SUM(ST_Distance(
        ST_LineInterpolatePoint(sfroads.geom_latest1, 
            ST_LineLocatePoint(sfroads.geom_latest1, sf.point_origin)),
        ST_LineInterpolatePoint(sfroads.geom_latest1, 
            ST_LineLocatePoint(sfroads.geom_latest1, sf2.point_dest))
    )) AS road_distance
FROM
    sf,
    sf2,
    sfroads 
WHERE sf.id in (84,4,5,8) and sf2.gid in (6,1,89,63,8)
GROUP BY sf.id, sf2.gid;
```

---

```
SELECT
    start.gid,
    end.gid,
    SUM(ST_Distance(
            ST_ClosestPoint(roads.geom, start.geom),
            ST_ClosestPoint(roads.geom, end.geom)
    )) AS road_distance
FROM
    start,
    end,
    roads
WHERE
    start.gid IN (84, 4, 5, 8) AND end.gid IN (6, 1, 89, 63, 8)
GROUP BY
    start.gid,
    end.gid;
```

Even though the datasets are in same projection system, the distance obtained is wrong. Did check the topology and corrected. The issue is that I'm getting the result but the results are not correct.

The above mentioned queries are the ones I tried to solve the issue. Both the queries failed to give the solution accordingly.

I used UTM 44N for Indian region, still the result is not correct. Used all possible Projection systems but no clue why the distance is not getting calculated

My requirement is to find the distance  between two points based on the road network.

Comment: you are measuring a straight line. See `pg_routing` for network length.

Comment: and for the straight line, make sure you are using a projection suitable for distance measurements (NOT 3857 or 4326)

Comment: "Failed to give a solution" isn't as descriptive as is necessary for a *problem-solving* site. **How** did it fail? What were you expecting? What did you get instead? Please [Edit] the Question (and include the SRID in use)